# How to Compare 2 LinkedHashMap and get difference in keys & values?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, linkedhashmap

There are 2 LinkedHashMaps. I have to check if both LinkedHashMaps have same keys & values. If one LinkedHashMap contains extra keys + values then it should get printed or stored in 3rd LinkedHashMap. If any of the key or value is different in 2nd LinkedHashMap then it should be notified (print in console)

Eg

Map1 contains {A-a, B-b, C-c}

Map2 contains {A-a, B-r, C-c, Z-z}

So here 3rd LinkedHashMap should contain {Z-z} as it contains extra key and

{B-r} should get printed as it is modified

Comment: Well ... And what problem do you have?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose need logic for that

Comment: StackOverflow community would be most helpful if you have tried something and stuck with something.
Anyways iterate over one list check for the key in the other list, if not found add to the third list, if the value is different print. While iterating remove from the second list so that you can add all the remaining entries of second list directly to third list at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this class :)

```
public class MapCompare {
    private LinkedHashMap<String, String> differencesMap;
    private LinkedHashMap<String, String> extraMap;

    private void main(LinkedHashMap<String, String> map1, LinkedHashMap<String, String> map2) {
        this.differencesMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        this.extraMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> set1 = ((LinkedHashMap<String, String>) map1.clone()).entrySet();
        Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> set2 = ((LinkedHashMap<String, String>) map2.clone()).entrySet();

        set1.removeAll(set2);
        compare(set1, map2);

        set1 = map1.entrySet();

        set2.removeAll(set1);
        compare(set2, map1);
    }

    private LinkedHashMap<String, String> getDifferencesMap() {
        return differencesMap;
    }

    private LinkedHashMap<String, String> getExtraMap() {
        return extraMap;
    }

    private void compare(Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> set, LinkedHashMap<String, String> map) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : set) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            if (map.containsKey(key) || map.containsValue(value)) {
                differencesMap.put(key, value);
            } else {
                extraMap.put(key, value);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> map1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map1.put("A", "a");
        map1.put("B", "b");
        map1.put("C", "c");
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> map2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map2.put("A", "a");
        map2.put("C", "c");
        map2.put("B", "r");
        map2.put("Z", "z");

        MapCompare mapCompare = new MapCompare();
        mapCompare.main(map1,map2);

        System.out.println("diff: " + mapCompare.getDifferencesMap());
        System.out.println("extra: " + mapCompare.getExtraMap());
    }
}
```